# Create javascript array using php to get images from directory

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, directory

I have a jquery function which relies on an array of images to create a fadeOut/In effect.

The line of code looks like this:

```
var images=new Array('/images/myImage1.jpg','/images/myImage2.jpg','/images/myImage3.jpg');
```

Currently I manually create this array but I would like to create it using php to grab the images in a directory on my server. I have found the following code which does this but I need to format so it looks like the javascript above.

```
<?php
$dir    = 'chamberImages/portfolio';
$files2 = scandir($dir, 1);
print_r($files2);
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just JSON encode the array that you have in `$files2`, removing the `.` and `..` entries with `array_slice`:

```
var images = <?php echo json_encode(array_slice($files2, 2)); ?>;
```

Comment: This seems to be almost what I need but it results in `var images=new Array["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg"];`
rather than
`var images=new Array('image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg');` which is what I need to get this working...

Comment: @Tom You don't need the `new Array` stuff. `var images=['x.jpg', 'y.jpg'];` format is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use json:

```
json_encode($files2);
```

The result is a json formatted string that can be used as javascript code to create the array.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax. If you can't or do not want to do it, here is an inline PHP solution:

```
var images=new Array('<?php echo implode("', '", $files2) ?>');
```